# Find $g(0)$ and $g'(0)$ given $g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y) + xy$ for all $x,y$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{g(x)}{x} = 4$

Tags: limits

**Question:** Let $g$ be a real valued function defined for all real $x$. Find $g(0)$ and $g'(0)$ given $g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y) + xy$ for all $x,y$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{g(x)}{x} = 4$

**My Attempt:** Make $ y = 0$, then we get $g(x+0)= g(x) + g(y) + xy = g(x) + g(0) \rightarrow g(x) - g(x) = g(0)$, Thus $g(0) =0$

$g'(x+0) = [g(x) + g(0)]' = [g(x)]'  = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x) + g(h) +xh-g(x)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h) +xh}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h)}{h} + \lim\limits_{h \to 0}x = x+4$

Thus $g'(0)= 4 + 0 = 4$. Is this approach/answer correct?

Comment: Once you know $g(0)=0$, you automatically know $g'(0)$ by definition of the derivative.

Comment: This is correct, but you could just skip the $g'(x+0)$ part. Starting with $g'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} [g(x+h)-g(x)]/h$ and going through the same steps gets you to $g'(x) = x+4$.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, but written in a quite complicated way.

Proving $g(0)=0$ is ok, but for $g'(0)$, you just have to notice that
$$\frac{g(x)}{x} = \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}$$

The fact that this quantity tends to $4$ when $x$ tends to $0$ is the definition of $g'(0)=4$.

Comment: There are two common equivalent definitions of the derivative, though no matter which you use, it's good to know the other as a property. The OP is using the other definition/property, but this one certainly makes this problem quicker.

Comment: Yes, the OP gave a correct answer. It just seems complicated to me, because it strongly uses the property on $g(x+y)=...$ to calcultate $g'(0)$, whereas the simple fact that $g(0)=0$ is sufficient.

Comment: Just commenting in case anyone had confusion over "is the definition".